# Display user profiles in a specific role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to display the profiles of users only in the `RegularUser` role. Only Administrators will be able to see all profiles, regardless of role.

Here's what I have so far in the view but it doesn't seem to work. Something about it just looks wrong:

```
 @string[] usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("RegularUser");
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <ul>
    @foreach (string FirstName in usersInRole)
    {
        <li>
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FullName)</h3>
            @if (item.Image != null)
            {
                <img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" alt="" />
            }
            else
            {
                <br />
            }
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
 }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you have in 'Model' ?

Comment: Oh yes, Model contains the fields of the UserProfile class. It works fine and displays profiles, but I can't seem to filter them by role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you to check if Users in Model are in RegularUser Role :

```
@string[] usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("RegularUser");
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if(usersInRole.Contains(item.Firstname))
    {
        <li>
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FullName)</h3>
            @if (item.Image != null)
            {
                <img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" alt="" />
            }
            else
            {
                <br />
            }
        </li>
    }
}
</ul>
```

If you want to limite this view to an admin, you can use :

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Administrator")){}
```

Hope it's help

Comment: Most awesome! 'if(usersInRole.Contains(item.Firstname))' fixed it. I had it backwards haha. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your for each loop is enumerating over the correct users for that role. But you aren't outputting their username anywhere. If you include

```
@FirstName
```

Inside for each you'll see users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display contents based on role. 
Try this

```
 @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
  { 
       //show all profiles
  }
  else
  {
       //show only regular users
  }
```

Comment: I've already added that functionality and I'm able to show different content to admins. Thanks.